# Pandas Pivoting Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as shown below, I would like to perform a pivot so that I can plot the top 3 countries GDP per year. So I need to pivot the datadrame in such a way that it returns me the the 3 Countries with the 3 highest GDP each year

Any ideas?

```
 Year  Country   GDP
 01    USA      100
 01    UK        80
 01    Japan     50
 01    China     75
 02    USA       90
 02    UK        65
 02    Japan     70
 02    China     80
```

Comment: Can you show how the desired result looks like?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069009/pandas-good-approach-to-get-top-n-records-within-each-group) answer your question, or are you asking about the subsequent plotting question?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
   Year Country  GDP
0     1     USA  100
1     1      UK   80
2     1   Japan   50
3     1   China   75
4     2     USA   90
5     2      UK   65
6     2   Japan   70
7     2   China   80

In [20]: df.sort_values(['Year', 'GDP'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('Year').head(3)
Out[20]: 
   Year Country  GDP
0     1     USA  100
1     1      UK   80
3     1   China   75
4     2     USA   90
7     2   China   80
6     2   Japan   70
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect, funny the ,head needs to be after the groupby to create the correct cut