# More efficient way to find top values in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with two columns    x    and    y    . Column    y    is cum count of     x    values.    x    values have different counts. How do I get a result df of top two    y    counts for each    x    without iterating through rows.

Example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [101, 101, 101, 101, 201, 201, 201, 405, 405], "y": [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]})

     x  y
0  101  1
1  101  2
2  101  3
3  101  4
4  201  1
5  201  2
6  201  3
7  405  1
8  405  2
```

Desired result:

```
x      y
101    3
101    4
201    2
201    3
405    1
405    2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32397818/2285236

Comment: do you really need a separate `y` column? can't you just use `df.x.count` to find out what the greatest y value would be. And then do some kind of masked duplication to get n-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
In [35]:
df.loc[df.groupby(['x'])['y'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-2:]).index.get_level_values(1)]

Out[35]:
     x  y
2  101  3
3  101  4
5  201  2
6  201  3
7  405  1
8  405  2
```

So this `groupby` on 'x' column and returns the last 2 values, assuming that the df is already sorted as you've shown. This produces a df with a multindex and the second level values can be used to index back into the original df by using `get_level_values`

**EDIT**

To answer your comment you can `groupby` again and use `transform` with `rank` to reset the values to `1` and `2`:

```
In [51]:
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby(['x'])['y'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-2:]).index.get_level_values(1)]
df1['y'] = df1.groupby('x')['y'].transform(lambda x: x.rank(method='first'))
df1
​
Out[51]:
     x  y
2  101  1
3  101  2
5  201  1
6  201  2
7  405  1
8  405  2
```

Comment: thanks, Follow-up to this solution, how would I reset    y     values to 1 and 2 for each unique x

Comment: Call `reset_index(drop=True)` on the above

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if your dataframe is not sorted:

```
In [1]: df.groupby('x')['y'].nlargest(2)
Out[1]: 
x     
101  3    4
     2    3
201  6    3
     5    2
405  8    2
     7    1
dtype: int64
```

Unfortunately `nlargest` cannot be applied to a grouped-by dataframe, so there is some reformatting to do.

Comment: You can do the same thing as I proposed, call `get_level_values(1)` on the index and use this to index back into the original df