# Get top n values per category in pandas retaining all columns

Tags: python, pandas

After some transformations I got the following `dataframe`, how do I proceed to obtain the top n records by a column in this case `short_name` and using other as indicator `frequency`. I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069009/pandas-good-approach-to-get-top-n-records-within-each-group) but the problem with both solutions is that they get rid of the column `product_name`, they just retain the grouped column and I need to keep them all.

```
short_name          product_id    frequency
Yoghurt y cereales  975009684     32
Yoghurt y cereales  975009685     21
Yoghurt y cereales  975009700     16
Yoghurt y Cereales  21097         16
Yoghurt Bebible     21329         68
Yoghurt Bebible     21328         67
Yoghurt Bebible     21500         31
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could first sort the dataframe, then use `groupby`:

```
df.sort_values('frequency', ascending=False).groupby('short_name').head(2)
Out[28]: 
           short_name  product_id  frequency
4     Yoghurt Bebible       21329         68
5     Yoghurt Bebible       21328         67
0  Yoghurt y cereales   975009684         32
1  Yoghurt y cereales   975009685         21
3  Yoghurt y Cereales       21097         16
```

Answer (score 10):

I'd try to use `nlargest` method:

```
In [5]: df.groupby('short_name', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, 'frequency'))
Out[5]:
             short_name  product_id  frequency
0 4     Yoghurt Bebible       21329         68
  5     Yoghurt Bebible       21328         67
1 3  Yoghurt y Cereales       21097         16
2 0  Yoghurt y cereales   975009684         32
  1  Yoghurt y cereales   975009685         21
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
df.groupby('short_name', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='frequency',ascending=False).head(2)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
           short_name  product_id  frequency
0     Yoghurt Bebible       21329         68
1     Yoghurt Bebible       21328         67
2  Yoghurt y Cereales       21097         16
3  Yoghurt y cereales   975009684         32
4  Yoghurt y cereales   975009685         21
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly using .apply is not necessary in this case. This is something I would avoid unless there's no other option because of performance issues.

Try this:

```
df.sort_values(by='frequency',ascending=False).groupby('short_name').head(2).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('short_name').nlargest(2, 'frequency').reset_index()
```