# How to keep top [2-31] rows of each group in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

[This anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32397818/6278334) said that I can use `df.groupby('id')['value'].nlargest(30)`to get top30 rows for each group.
But how to get the rows form top2 to top31 for each group?  Is there a function that can do the similar thing like `pandas.Series.nlargest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `apply` and `.iloc` to get , for example you want 1:30

```
df.sort_values('value').groupby('id').value.apply(lambda x : x.iloc[1:30])
```

Comment: But the question was from nlargest right? `top 2 - 31`. Maybe you need to `sort_values`?

Comment: @Dawei Yw~ have a nice day :-)