# pandas query a grouping within a grouping

Tags: mysql, pandas, dataframe

Having trouble writing a query where I can get the top 10 of a top 10 based on a count

My starting table from this query:

```
top_10_cars = 'CH', 'DA', 'AG', 'DC', 'LA', 'NY', 'SA', 'SE', 'DE', 'MI'

df = pd.read_sql("select\
                    count(*) as count\
                    ,ID\
                    ,CAR\
                    from "+db+"\
                    where pop in ('"+ "','".join(top_10_cars) +"')\
                    group by\
                    pop\
                    ,asn\
                    order by reqs desc\
                     ",conn)
```

Result is a list with all the IDs for every car grouping sorted by count:

```
Count       ID  CAR
67210048    7922    CH
2081655     20001   LA
488850583   7018    AG
567585985   7018    DA
450991      7922    SA
41123124    7018    CH
4135532     11427   DA
...
..
.
```

The dataframe above is too big. I only one that top 10 Ids for each car.

For example CH:

```
Count       ID  CAR
67210048    7922    CH
25100548    7546    CH
465100      8542    CH
67254828    5622    CH
1251048     3522    CH
...
..
.
```

The resulting table should look like this

```
Count       ID  CAR
67210048    7922    CH
25100548    7546    CH
..
.
7210048     1546    DA
251005      5678    DA
25100548    7546    DA
465100      8542    DA
...
..
67254828    5622    DA
and 
so 
on.. 'AG', 'DC', 'LA', 'NY', 'SA', 'SE', 'DE', 'MI'
```

Comment: This answer might help- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069009/pandas-get-topmost-n-records-within-each-group

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal trying to do that in the query.. but I ended up with a .. pythonic solution (open to a sql though)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the correct way to do this but I just wrapped it some python:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in top_NA_cars:
    dftemp = pd.read_sql("select\
                            count(*) as count\
                            ,ID\
                            ,CAR\
                            from "+db+"\
                            where CAR in ('"+x+"')\
                            group by\
                            ID\
                            ,CAR\
                            order by count desc limit 10",conn)
    df = df.append(dftemp)
```

Open to better solutions but ^ did work.