# Select the n Largest values when there are more than one Groups

Tags: pandas

```
test= pd.DataFrame({'Year':['2016','2016','2016','2017','2017','2017']
                    ,'Country' : ['NL','GR','AU','NL','GB','BR']
                    ,'Count' : ['100','200','5','1000','2000','3']}) 
df;

    Year    Country Count
0   2016    NL      100
1   2016    GR      200
2   2016    AU      5
3   2017    NL      1000
4   2017    GB      2000
5   2017    BR      3
```

I would like to select the top 2 entries based on Column Count and Year.

such as

```
    Year  Country   Count
0   2016    NL      100
1   2016    GR      200
3   2017    NL      1000
4   2017    GB      2000
```

So for each year I want to see the top 2 countries. Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas get topmost n records within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069009/pandas-get-topmost-n-records-within-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

First is necessary convert column `Count` to integers, then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last use [`GroupBy.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html) or [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
test['Count'] = test['Count'].astype(int)
df = test.sort_values(['Year','Count']).groupby('Year').tail(2)
print (df)
   Year Country  Count
0  2016      NL    100
1  2016      GR    200
3  2017      NL   1000
4  2017      GB   2000
```

If want change order in `count` column:

```
test['Count'] = test['Count'].astype(int)
df = test.sort_values(['Year','Count'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('Year').head(2)
print (df)
   Year Country  Count
1  2016      GR    200
0  2016      NL    100
4  2017      GB   2000
3  2017      NL   1000
```