# How do I extract the top 3 results from each key in a Python DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm currently analysing a set of data and have columns named "Genre", "Actor" and "Rating".

With Genre as the main key, how should I go about acquiring the top 3 rated actors from each genre?

I've tried to initially sort the ratings in descending order first and then subsequently, taking the top 3 highest rated actors. However, this results in a jumbled mess when trying to parse it through

```
data1 = data.groupby(["genre0", "Actor0"])[["Rating"]].mean().sort_values("Rating", ascending=False)
data2 = data.groupby(["genre0", "Actor1"])[["Rating"]].mean().sort_values("Rating", ascending=False)
data3 = data.groupby(["genre0", "Actor2"])[["Rating"]].mean().sort_values("Rating", ascending=False)


allgenres = pd.concat([data1, data2, data3])

allgenres.groupby("genre0").head(3)
```

The output should reflect:

(Genre) - (Actors Names) - (Top 3 Rated Actors)

E.g.

```
Action - Actor A - 10
         Actor B - 9
         Actor C - 8

Animation - Actor D - 10
            Actor E - 9
            Actor F - 8

I do not wish to reset the index and keep the ordering as it is, but group the results together.
```

[My Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcILR.png)

Comment: You can try to sort, then drop duplicates (setting keep='first') by key and then take the first three rows.

Comment: For my current work, I do not mind duplicates though! However, how do I combine the genres from my picture?

Comment: @tabbakhh read that but it isn’t, sadly :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas get topmost n records within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069009/pandas-get-topmost-n-records-within-each-group)

Comment: Please show your input data in a reproducible way.