# Get 3 most most expansive city for each state

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get 3 cities with the biggest "raised" value for each state based on the dataframe below.

So, there is a number of campaigns for each city. I want to sum up "raised" amounts for each of the cities, to get a total raised amount for each city, and then to display three top cities cities in terms of the "raised" amount for each state.

```
     category                  city            created     goal                                               name   raised state                                                url
0     Medical                OXNARD  December 30, 2018  15000.0                           Wayne's Cancer Care Fund     80.0    CA  https://www.gofundme.com/8qz8h6-waynes-cancer-...
1     Medical           CHINO HILLS   December 4, 2018   2000.0            Mother of two has cancer and needs help    500.0    CA                   https://www.gofundme.com/3qi0rog
2     Medical          BATTLE CREEK   December 6, 2018  10000.0                                     Hospital costs    570.0    MI                   https://www.gofundme.com/3sbwals
3     Medical  FEASTERVILLE TREVOSE   December 3, 2018  10000.0                          Help raise Joey & Brianna   2200.0    MI         https://www.gofundme.com/get-away-from-him
4     Medical       WEST PALM BEACH  December 12, 2018   6000.0                        Kelvin McCray Recovery Fund   2450.0    MI      https://www.gofundme.com/send-ricky-to-school
5     Medical                 JONES  December 11, 2018  25000.0           Wheelchair Accessible Vehicle for Taelor   2270.0    OK       https://www.gofundme.com/HelpTaelorTransport
6     Medical                CONROE  December 20, 2018  10000.0                       "A Good friend in dire need"   1250.0    OK                   https://www.gofundme.com/4dmeoko
```

Sample date in json:

```
[{
    "category": "Medical",
    "city": "OXNARD",
    "created": "December 30, 2018",
    "goal": 15000.0,
    "name": "Wayne's Cancer Care Fund",
    "raised": 80.0,
    "state": "CA",
    "url": "https://www.gofundme.com/8qz8h6-waynes-cancer-care-fund"
},
{
    "category": "Medical",
    "city": "CHINO HILLS",
    "created": "December 4, 2018",
    "goal": 2000.0,
    "name": "Mother of two has cancer and needs help",
    "raised": 500.0,
    "state": "CA",
    "url": "https://www.gofundme.com/3qi0rog"
},

{
    "category": "Medical",
    "city": "BATTLE CREEK",
    "created": "December 6, 2018",
    "goal": 10000.0,
    "name": "Hospital costs",
    "raised": 570.0,
    "state": "MI",
    "url": "https://www.gofundme.com/3sbwals"
},
{
    "category": "Medical",
    "city": "FEASTERVILLE TREVOSE",
    "created": "December 3, 2018",
    "goal": 10000.0,
    "name": "Help raise Joey & Brianna",
    "raised": 2200.0,
    "state": "MI",
    "url": "https://www.gofundme.com/get-away-from-him"
},
{
    "category": "Medical",
    "city": "WEST PALM BEACH",
    "created": "December 12, 2018",
    "goal": 6000.0,
    "name": "Kelvin McCray Recovery Fund",
    "raised": 2450.0,
    "state": "MI",
    "url": "https://www.gofundme.com/send-ricky-to-school"
},
{
    "category": "Medical",
    "city": "JONES",
    "created": "December 11, 2018",
    "goal": 25000.0,
    "name": "Wheelchair Accessible Vehicle for Taelor",
    "raised": 2270.0,
    "state": "OK",
    "url": "https://www.gofundme.com/HelpTaelorTransport"
},
{
    "category": "Medical",
    "city": "CONROE",
    "created": "December 20, 2018",
    "goal": 10000.0,
    "name": "\"A Good friend in dire need\"",
    "raised": 1250.0,
    "state": "OK",
    "url": "https://www.gofundme.com/4dmeoko"
}]
```

The expected outcome should look like this:

```
123 State1 City1 100 
3          City2 99  
58         City3 98  
8   State2 City4 97  
12         City5 96  
1          City6 95
```

this doesn't really help:

```
maxRaisedCityByState = a.df.groupby(['state','city'])['raised'].max()
```

The answers from the allegedly [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069009/pandas-get-topmost-n-records-within-each-group) do not help:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20069379/5286299 - does not work, because I need only city, state, raised and goal columns to be displayed, also I need them to be sorted by state and within the state by raised.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32397818/5286299 - does not work, because I also have to see the city

Comment: gives me the following result: "TRENTON"

Comment: Voting to reopen because the duplicate does not fully explain why or how the dataframe needs to be sorted with `df = df.sort('raised',ascending=False)` before using `df.groupby('state').head(2).reset_index(drop=True)` It only mentions possibly needing to "order/sort"  without explaining how.

Comment: @double-beep, I replaced the pic with the code and added the data sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified the city and state names to make it easier to follow.

Allow me to experiment with a new solution for table formatting :)

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>category</th><th>city</th><th>created</th><th>goal</th><th>name</th><th>raised</th><th>state</th><th>url</th><th> </th></tr><tr><td>0</td><td>Medical</td><td>City1</td><td>December 30, 2018</td><td>15000.0</td><td>Wayne's Cancer Care Fund</td><td>80.0</td><td>State1</td><td>https://www.gofundme.com/8qz8h6-waynes-cancer-...</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Medical</td><td>City1</td><td>December 4, 2018</td><td>2000.0</td><td>Mother of two has cancer and needs help</td><td>500.0</td><td>State1</td><td>https://www.gofundme.com/3qi0rog</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Medical</td><td>City2</td><td>December 6, 2018</td><td>10000.0</td><td>Hospital costs</td><td>570.0</td><td>State1</td><td>https://www.gofundme.com/3sbwals</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Medical</td><td>City3</td><td>December 3, 2018</td><td>10000.0</td><td>Help raise Joey &amp; Brianna</td><td>2200.0</td><td>State1</td><td>https://www.gofundme.com/get-away-from-him</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>Medical</td><td>City4</td><td>December 12, 2018</td><td>6000.0</td><td>Kelvin McCray Recovery Fund</td><td>2450.0</td><td>State2</td><td>https://www.gofundme.com/send-ricky-to-school</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>Medical</td><td>City5</td><td>December 11, 2018</td><td>25000.0</td><td>Wheelchair Accessible Vehicle for Taelor</td><td>2270.0</td><td>State2</td><td>https://www.gofundme.com/HelpTaelorTransport</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>Medical</td><td>City6</td><td>December 20, 2018</td><td>10000.0</td><td>"A Good friend in dire need"</td><td>1250.0</td><td>State2</td><td>https://www.gofundme.com/4dmeoko</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Step 1: Drop unneeded columns:

```
df.drop(['category', 'created', 'goal', 'name', 'url'], inplace=True, axis = 1)
```

Which gives us:

```
    city    raised  state
0   City1   80.0    State1
1   City1   500.0   State1
2   City2   570.0   State1
3   City3   2200.0  State1
4   City4   2450.0  State2
5   City5   2270.0  State2
6   City6   1250.0  State2
```

Step2: Group by state & city and sum their raised amounts (only city1 in this example):

```
df = df.groupby(['state', 'city']).sum()
```

Now we have:

```
                raised
state   city    
State1  City1   580.0
        City2   570.0
        City3   2200.0
State2  City4   2450.0
        City5   2270.0
        City6   1250.0
```

Note our index went from being numerical to multilevel. Level 1 being state level 2 being the city.

Step 3: Sort by amount raised. As expected this ignores the multi-index order so after sorting we need to re-sort the index. We only sort by level 0 which is the state. :

```
df.sort_values('raised', ascending=False).sort_index(level=[0], sort_remaining=False).groupby('state').head(3)
```

Finally we have:

```
                raised
state   city    
State1  City3   2200.0
        City1   580.0
        City2   570.0
State2  City4   2450.0
        City5   2270.0
        City6   1250.0
```

Comment: this one seems to be working:  a.df.sort_values('raised', ascending=False).sort_index(level=[0], sort_remaining=False).groupby('state').head(3)

I am accepting your answer, just add this last line of code from my comment into it, becuase I need to select top "n" cities

Comment: No problem, amended the answer.