# Top 2 products counts per day Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe like in the below pic.

First; I want the top 2 products, second I need the top 2 products frequents per day, so I need to group it by days and select the top 2 products from products column, I tried this code but it gives an error.

`df.groupby("days", as_index=False)(["products"] == "Follow Up").count()`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrNIS.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: you can use [pandas.Series.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get top-n of a column, for top-n after groupby refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069009/pandas-get-topmost-n-records-within-each-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `groupby` over both days and products and then use `size`. Once you have done this you will have all the counts in the `df` you require.

You will then need to sort both the `day` and the default `0` column which now contains your counts, this has been created by resetting your index on the initial `groupby`.

We follow the instructions in [Pandas get topmost n records within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069009/pandas-get-topmost-n-records-within-each-group) to give your desired result.

A full example:

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'day':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3],
'value':['a','a','b','b','b','c','a','a','b','b','b','c','a','a','b','b','b','c']})
```

```
df.head(6)

    day value
0   1   a
1   1   a
2   1   b
3   1   b
4   1   b
5   1   c
```

```
df_counts = df.groupby(['day','values']).size().reset_index().sort_values(['day', 0], ascending = [True, False])
df_top_2 = df_counts.groupby('day').head(2)
```

```
df_top_2

   day value 0
1   1   b   3
0   1   a   2
4   2   b   3
3   2   a   2
7   3   b   3
6   3   a   2
```

Of course, you should rename the `0` column to something more reasonable but this is a minimal example.

Comment: Many thanks dear this is really helped me a lot, last question can you plot this using bokeh line graph I'm sorry I'm new to python and really confused if you have any tutorials recommendation will be appreciated