# **How to filter out item as per their frequency?**

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need a max of 3 **link** (results) from a single **domain_name** & need to discard other.
I have tried doing with **panda groupbuy** but didn't get success.
Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.groupby('domain_name').head(3)` should do the trick.

(see [Pandas get topmost n records within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069009/pandas-get-topmost-n-records-within-each-group))