# How to filter only record details which have max date

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get the record details which have the max date. How to get in pandas dataframe

```
ID  Name  Date
23  rtd   23/12/2020 12:23:10
23  wer   10/12/2020 10:34:09
10  rea   11/09/2020 20:23:10
10  rea   12/09/2020 11:23:23
12  erw   10/11/2020 12:23:20
```

output

```
ID  Name   Date
23  rtd   23/12/2020 12:23:10
10  rea   12/09/2020 11:23:23
12  erw   10/11/2020 12:23:20
```

Comment: Convert `Date` to datetimes and then use `df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['Date'].idxmax()]`

Comment: how to get the last two records from max date?

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069009/pandas-get-topmost-n-records-within-each-group)

Comment: df1.loc[df1.groupby('ID')['DATE'].idxmax().head(2) . i run this code but I didn't get correct answer. it filter only top 2 records. but I need from max date