# How to retrieve rows from DataFrame based on their first appearance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I generated a dataset that shows the similarity between users in a graph based on their neighbors.
Based on a dataset that shows the trust relations between users in a social network, I'm aiming to build a new dataset that contains the most similar users to my "trustor" user (e.g. the 3 most similar ones) by using a similarity evaluation algorithm.
I have listed the users in descending order so that the first time a new "trustor" appears, his/her most similar users appear at first.

```
new_trust.sort_values(['truster','value'],ascending=False)
```

[image: the dataframe I reproduce after the similarity algorithm]

So basically I need to keep only the 3 first appearances of each user in my dataframe.
I tried to do a `for i in range(new_trust.len())`: but couldn't quite find it.

Comment: add code for reproducing

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069009/pandas-get-topmost-n-records-within-each-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user is being your column truster you can use a `groupby` and get the first 3 appearances.

```
arr = {'truster':{0:1642,1:1642,2:1642,3:1642,4:1642,5:2,6:2,7:2,8:2,9:2},'trustee':{0:1570,1:524,2:1039,3:1545,4:1360,5:1388,6:658,7:1078,8:1336,9:1157},'value':{0:'0,08',1:'0,0533333',2:'0,04',3:'0,04',4:'0,022857',5:'0,001175',6:'0,001169',7:'0,001169',8:'0,001169',9:'0,000902'}}
df_ = pd.from_dict(arr)
df = df_.groupby(['truster']).head(3)

   truster  trustee      value
0     1642     1570       0,08
1     1642      524  0,0533333
2     1642     1039       0,04
5        2     1388   0,001175
6        2      658   0,001169
7        2     1078   0,001169
```

An other solution would be to use `cumcount`:

```
df_['tmp_seq'] = df_.groupby(['truster']).cumcount()
df = df_.loc[df_['tmp_seq'] < 3]
```

Comment: I interpret it as if the algoritm of similarity was already done, and that OP only wants to keep the 3 first cols after the sorts "`So basically I need to keep only the 3 first appearances of each user in my dataframe`"

Comment: Ya, so then it is dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069009/pandas-get-topmost-n-records-within-each-group

Comment: The nlargest seems to return a series while the one aforementioned returns a dataftame. I can easily now concat() the two dataframes to add the n most similar users as trustees.