# How to select data 3 times in row dataframe greater threshold - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select 3 residual data that only pass through the threshold in a row, where my threshold is 3. Here I attach the csv data to the link and what I currently do is for the filter. where I need the time criteria there. Consecutive data are those that pass the threshold and are sequentially timed

```
df[df.residual_value >= 3]
```

[Data csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n-UI5xZGxmQecYViD8ArGkspOSVuRRJW/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Data]

[image: after residual < 3]

Comment: Do you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069009/pandas-get-topmost-n-records-within-each-group) ?

Comment: @jezrael what about the timing? because I think 3 consecutive data that passes through the threshold are consecutive data according to time

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to filter the rows that are greater or equal than 3, only if 3 consecutive rows match the criterion. You can use `rolling`+`min`:

processing:

```
df[df['col'].rolling(window=3).min().shift(-2).ge(3)]
```

example dataset:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.random.randint(0,10,100)})
```

```
>>> df.head(15)
    col
0     5
1     0
2     3
3     3
4     7
5     9
6     3
7     5
8     2
9     4
10    7
11    6
12    8
13    8
14    1
```

output:

```
    col
2     3
3     3
4     7
5     9
9     4
10    7
11    6
...
```